# Regex Difference Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.x

I want to port this code from python2 to python3

```py
p = re.compile(ur"(?s)<u>(.*?)<\/u>")
subst = "\underline{\\1}"
raw_html = re.sub(p, subst, raw_html)
```

I figured out already that the `ur` shall be changed to just `r`:

```py
p = re.compile(r"(?s)<u>(.*?)<\/u>")
subst = "\underline{\\1}"
raw_html = re.sub(p, subst, raw_html)
```

however it does not work it complains about this:

```
cd build && PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore" python3 ../src/katalog.py --katalog 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/katalog.py", line 11, in <module>
    from common import *
  File "src/common.py", line 207
    subst = "\underline{\\1}"
                             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
make: *** [katalog1] Error 1
```

however changing it to "\underline" does not help either. It is not replacing it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
raw_html = r"<u>1</u> and <u>2</u>"
p = re.compile(r"(?s)<u>(.*?)</u>")
subst = r"\\underline{\1}"
raw_html = re.sub(p, subst, raw_html)
print(raw_html)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEX3@Yohq0RKpLqt7Y8EpNqBBvJikiAifntMCwouD@dwb3zmNfhzrcbFQBkIGc2P65qdhQsQH8rYD8cywuwXaHDagLO4SVT34KKxKIiLKcmmhTpMck8kS@WW8j6idfELkjUeX7p/878LVC0UsYO97@DrJItkfBY/rvUD), the results are `\underline{1} and \underline{2}`. Basically, inside replacement, use double backslash to replace with a single backslash. Use raw string literals to make life easier with regex in Python.

Comment: Absolute correct. Thanks for the clarification!